# How can I swap two values from particular column in a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Consider a table test contains an attributes of id and name.

The values for that.

```
Id   |   Name
1    |   Raj
2    |   Kumar
```

From the above sample table, I know only the id, So through the Id I need to swap  the name, like given below,

```
Id   |   Name
1    |   Kumar
2    |   Raj
```

Comment: Is this in a query? Or do you want to perform an update?

Comment: What ever, but it need to swap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
update the_table
   set name = case id
                 when 1 then (select name from the_table where id = 2)
                 when 2 then (select name from the_table where id = 1)
              end
where id in (1,2);
```

This assumes that `id` is unique (e.g. the primary key)

Comment: Can you explain your query line by line, How its work....

Answer (score 4):

One more way, which can be modified easily to do more complicated changes (e.g. swap multiple couples or move values from 1->2->3->1, update multiple columns, etc.):

```
with changes (update_id, take_value_from_id) as
    ( values
        (1, 2),    -- update row with id=1 from row with id=2
        (2, 1)     -- update row with id=2 from row with id=1
    ),
  data as
    ( select c.update_id, val.name
      from changes as c
        join the_table as val  on val.id = c.take_value_from_id
    )
update the_table as upd
set name = d.name 
from data as d  
where upd.id = d.update_id ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just swap the IDs instead of the value(s)? Or do the other columns have to remain as they were?

Anyway, in case someone else reads this question and is looking for this, it's just:

```
select case id when 1 then 2 when 2 then 1 else id end as id, ...other columns... from ...table...;
```

or as an update:

```
update ...table... set id = (case id when 1 then 2 when 2 then 1 else id end);
```

(I can never remember if the `else id` clause is needed.)

Comment: The `else id` is needed unless you have a `where id in (1,2)` which is good to have anyway. No need to update the whole table when only 2 rows need updating.

Comment: Your query is okay, it's work. But I need to swap the name not a id. Because if you swap id, Then the id is not in order.

Comment: Huh? Data in a table or in query results are never in any particular order. And if you are relying on a particular ordering because of the way a query works, or the way in which the data happens to be stored, your queries are broken.

To achieve a particular ordering, you *need* to use `order by`.

Comment: Update doesn't work in postgres as each set is checked against constraints individually

Comment: @PedroBorges You're right, thanks. Needs deferred constraints to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4b12787389d95343a4fe111eb379dae0

Answer (score 1):

We can swap two values from a particular row by using the 'With Query'.
Using 'with' we can take the backup and use it.
The query to solve the requirement,

```
with backup1 as (select name from test where id = 2), 
     backup2 as (update test set name = (select name from test where id = 1) where id = 2)
update test set name = (select * from backup1) where id = 1;
```

In the above query, the backup1 contains the name of whose id is 2, After that using update query I took the name of whose id is 1 and
stored in the name field where id is 2.
Then again using the update query I took the name from the backup and stored in the name field where id is 1, Like this we can swap.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions suggested before don't work if the name column is unique, as postgresql evaluates that constraint after each statement. Deferred constraints was mentioned, but often you can't modify the constraints you've been given.

So you'll need to use temp variables then. This is what I did in such a case. It's more than simple query, but adding it here as it resolved my use case and I think I might need this in the future.

```
DO $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
DECLARE temp VARCHAR;
DECLARE temp2 VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    -- first get the id pairs that need swapping
    -- naturally not needed if known beforehand
    -- so in that case you don't need the loop

    FOR r IN SELECT
             person.id AS person1_id, person2.id AS person2_id
             FROM (... some query..)
    LOOP
        -- swap through temp variables, since unique index
        -- and postgresql always evaluates them immediately

        SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = r.person1_id INTO temp;
        SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = r.person2_id INTO temp2;
        UPDATE person SET name = 'xxx' WHERE id = r.person1_id;
        UPDATE person SET name = temp WHERE id = r.person2_id;
        UPDATE person SET name = temp2 WHERE id = r.person1_id;

    END LOOP;
END$$;
```