# Flip a flag from one row to another in a single query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE rollouts
(
    id           UUID        PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    device_id    TEXT        NOT NULL,
    is_active    BOOLEAN     NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

How can I flip the `is_active` flag from one row to another for a given `device_id` and `id`?

Eg, go from

```
ID    DEVICE    IS_ACTIVE
1     D1        TRUE
2     D1        FALSE
```

to

```
ID    DEVICE    IS_ACTIVE
1     D1        FALSE
2     D1        TRUE
```

in  single query?

Because this won't clear the flag for ID=1:

```
UPDATE table SET is_active = true WHERE device=d1 AND ID=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just flip it for both:

```
update the_table
   set is_active = not is_active
where device = 'd1'
  and id in (1,2);
```

For a more general approach see: 
 
[How can I swap two values from particular column in a table in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131118/)

Comment: The linked general approach was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Turns out it doesn't work, because it'll clash with the partial index from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268510/ ("ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rollouts_active_idx"").